# How does the MailAddress constructor validate mail addresses

Tags: c#

In reading about what would be the best way to validate a mail address via regular expressions, I came across with an attempt to validate with

```
try
{
    new MailAddress(input);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // invalid
}
```

What method does the `MailAddress` class use to ensure a mail address is valid?

Comment: If you have access to Reflector, or another 'decompiler', you could take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by validate whether or not it's a valid e-mail address format, it supports several standard formats:

The MailAddress class supports the following mail address formats:

> A simple address format of user@host. If a DisplayName is not set,
>   this is the mail address format generated.
>
> A standard quoted display name format of "display name" .
>   If a DisplayName is set, this is the format generated.
>
> Angle brackets are added around the User name, Host name for "display
>   name" user@host if these are not included.
>
> Quotes are added around the DisplayName for display name ,
>   if these are not included.
>
> Unicode characters are supported in the DisplayName. property.
>
> A User name with quotes. For example, "user name"@host.
>
> Consecutive and trailing dots in user names. For example,
>   user...name..@host.
>
> Bracketed domain literals. For example, .
>
> Comments. For example, (comment)"display
>   name"(comment)<(comment)user(comment)@(comment)domain(comment)>(comment).
>   Comments are removed before transmission

.

This is from [MailAddress Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx)

As for what method it uses to validate the formats, I don't know.  You could always try Reflector to see what it's doing internally.  Is there a particular reason you want to know the internal details?

Comment: Sheer curiosity. I was wondering how it determines whether you provided a valid mail address. Not so much what parameters it takes, but how it validates the mail address itself.

Comment: Then Reflector or some other decompiler (like ILDASM, if nothing else is avaiable for you) would give you an idea of what the internal code is doing and how it's doing it.

Answer (score 6):

You can see the source code without using Reflector using the new [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/). Here's the link to the [MailAddress](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddress.cs#b23cf10c5d2b82f1) class.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx)

> The address parameter can contain a display name and the associated
>   e-mail address if you enclose the address in angle brackets. For
>   example:
>
> "Tom Smith <tsmith@contoso.com>"
>
> White space is permitted between the display name and the angle
>   brackets.

So a "naked" address such as tsmith@contos.com or one with a displayed name as mentioned in the documentation is fine. It is impossible to tell how the validation is done internally without access to the code, but a regex doing that validation can of course be constructed.